# How can I put the row number of a database in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

there is my problem :

```
{
const row_nb = con.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username = '"+username_ins+"'");
console.log(""+row_nb);
}
```

but I dont have the row number why ?
it return  [Object object]
And it's in javaScript

Comment: We dont know what RDMS you're using but im sure you'll find an SQL function that does it if you google it

Comment: I mean what is : mysqli_num_rows() in jQuery ?

Comment: Try `const row_nb = con.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Users WHERE username = '"+username_ins+"'");` after that `row_nb.total`

Comment: Or try console `console.log(row_nb) ` variable for watching what it is

Comment: I tried but it log "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`con.query` is an async method you have to pass the callback to get the result.

```
var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as usersCount FROM Users WHERE username = ?"
con.query(sql, [username_ins], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Query result: ', rows[0].usersCount);
});
```

Comment: I have
 Query result:  [ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(*)': 11 } ] 
but I need only a number how can i do plz ?

Comment: it log undefined